# SELECT or do I need an UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I run a select statement that picks words out of the records from a note field using a `WHERE` condition.

I would like a field in the SQL to tell me which word it found in the note field.
How can I do this?

Is this when you use an UPDATE on the original SELECT statement or is there a way to do this with one pass?  I am sorry to ask such a newbie question but I am new to Oracle.

```
SELECT ZOOANIMALS.MOPID,
       ZOOANIMALS.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED "TYPE",
       '          ' AS FOUND_THIS,
       ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE
FROM MOPUSER.ZOOANIMALS
INNER JOIN MOPUSER.ZOONOTES ON ZOOANIMALS.MOPID=ZOONOTES.MOPID
WHERE ZOOANIMALS.mopstart BETWEEN sysdate AND (sysdate+14)
  AND UPPER(ZOOANIMALS.MOPSTATUS) != 'COMPLETE'
  AND UPPER(ZOOANIMALS.MOPSTATUS) != 'CANCELLED'
  AND (ZOOANIMALS.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED LIKE '%FTTT%'
       OR (UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE ''%AARDVARK%'
           OR UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE '%ZEBRA%'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in your SELECT clause to test for which case it is.

```
SELECT ZOOANIMALS.MOPID,
ZOOANIMALS.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED "TYPE",
'          ' as FOUND_THIS,
    ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE,
CASE WHEN ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE LIKE '%FTTT%' THEN 'FTTT WAS TRIGGERED' else '' end,
CASE WHEN UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE '%AARDVARK%' THEN 'AARDVARK WAS TRIGGERED' else '' end,
CASE WHEN UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE '%ZEBRA%' THEN 'ZEBRA WAS TRIGGERED' else '' end

FROM MOPUSER.ZOOANIMALS INNER JOIN MOPUSER.ZOONOTES ON ZOOANIMALS.MOPID=ZOONOTES.MOPID
WHERE ZOOANIMALS.mopstart between sysdate and (sysdate+14)
AND UPPER(ZOOANIMALS.MOPSTATUS) != 'COMPLETE'
AND UPPER(ZOOANIMALS.MOPSTATUS) != 'CANCELLED'
AND
(
ZOOANIMALS.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED LIKE '%FTTT%'
    OR
    (
    UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE ''%AARDVARK%'
    OR UPPER(ZOONOTES.MOPNOTE) LIKE '%ZEBRA%'
 )
 )
```